# Is jq installed and available on PATH?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, jq, yq

I am trying to read a yaml file in gitlab CI. I installed `jq==1.0.2` and `yq==2.10.1` using `pip` in my CI job and I use python:3.7 image. When I tried to read the yaml file, it has the error

```
yq: Error starting jq: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jq': 'jq'. Is jq installed and available on PATH?
```

My yaml file is not call jq and I do have this yaml file in my commit. I am able to do `which yq`, when I do `which jq`, the CI job failed. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `jq` installation is not quite correct. Your version information `jq==1.0.2` indicates that you have installed the python package `jq` - https://pypi.org/project/jq/ which is not the same as the executable binary `jq` that gets installed. You need the executable to be installed, before invoking the `yq` tool.

Since `yq` looks in `PATH` for availability of the `jq` binary, but doesn't find it, you get the runtime error indicating the absence. The fix will be setup your CI to download the `jq` binary from one of the steps mentioned in https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo apt-get install jq` not `pip3 install jq`.